# how to remove margin between elements

Tags: css, sass

I do have a `div` that has a image and another `div` with a h4 and p tag. After assigning `flex` to the parent div, the h4 and p tag have a margin which cannot be eliminated.

The green marked place must be eliminated

[image]

Code:

```
<div className={styles.profile}>
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/sfuyyLvyUx636_Oq3Fw5_mt-PIc=/3760x2820/smart/filters:no_upscale()/adorable-white-pomeranian-puppy-spitz-921029690-5c8be25d46e0fb000172effe.jpg"
          alt="sai"
        />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.profile__name}>
        <h4>TEST USER</h4>
        <p>Premium Member</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Style:

```
.profile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 32px rgba(234, 19, 19, 0.45));
  }
}
```

I tried giving margin:0 to .profile__name but still the margin stays there.

Comment: try to add ``margin: 0;`` on ``h4``  and ``p``    tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `margin: 0;` on `h4`  and `p` tag

```
.profile h4, .profile p{
    margin: 0;
}
```